# Accessing char pointer in a struct which was casted from a void pointer

Tags: c, pointers, casting, void-pointers

i'm a little bit confused about this:

My function `fillData(void* db)` should be passed a pointer to the struct `tdpatientProfile`, which is contained in the struct `tdWAKDAllStateConfigure` as a member named `patientProfile`. I only have a `void` Pointer `pData` (which is a `tdWAKDAllStateConfigure` pointer passed as `void*`), which is a member of another struct `Qtoken`, so i need to cast the `void` pointer to `tdWAKDAllStateConfigure` before i can access `patientProfile`. Because at that point `patientProfile` is already dereferenced but i need a pointer to it, i add a `&` to the beginning.

```
&(((tdWAKDAllStateConfigure*)Qtoken.pData)->patientProfile)
```

This should work in theory but `patientProfile` has a member char pointer `name[50]` which should be filled by using `strncpy`. Inside `filldata`, i cast the `void` pointer back inside my `strncpy` call.

```
strncpy(((tdPatientProfile*)db)->name, sourcestring, passedChars)
```

At this point, my code crashed. I can't verify if it is correctly casted because they're void pointers, so i can't look them up in the debugger and the memory view of insight doesn't work because this runs on a virtual ARM platform where i connect with gdb/insight to debug it.

After 2 hours of testing and debugging i don't get it. Does anybody here got a clue what goes wrong?

ok, more code, this is no public code so i'll try to cut it down to the least amount.

I have a database thread, which calls a function which should read in values from a file. The database thread has a local member Qtoken which contains a void pointer pData where the values from the files should be written to. The function call inside the database thread is:

```
unified_read(dataID_PatientProfile,&(((tdWAKDAllStateConfigure*)Qtoken.pData)->patientProfile))
```

Header:

```
uint8_t unified_read(tdDataId datatype, void* db);
```

Inside unified_read, i open the file etc. and call another function which should parse the data inside the file to a ; and copy the previous chars into char name[50] of patientProfile. Function call to the parse function:

```
parseString(&ptr, ((tdPatientProfile*)db)->name, 50);
```

Header

```
uint8_t parseString(char** ptr, char* destination, size_t destinationSize)
```

inside the parse function everything is okay (ptr needs to be a double pointer because it needs to be increased, this works as destinationSize is correct and the dereferenced ptr too), it will find ; after 16 chars and saves it in passedChars. But this strncpy function call breaks it and crashed my code:

```
strncpy(destination, *ptr, passedChars);
```

Ah well i should add: I had this problem 2 weeks ago and just changed the code that unified_read gets passed a pointer to tdWAKDAllStateConfigure and dereferences patientProfile by itself. This worked perfectly but my coding chief doesn't want to pass the whole tdWAKDAllStateConfigure just for changing the patientProfile member inside it.

**Another test:**

```
tdPatientProfile testomat;
char str1[]= "To be or not to be";
strncpy(testomat.name, str1, 15);

if(!unified_read(dataID_PatientProfile,&testomat))
```

this works as intended. So my casting &(((tdWAKDAllStateConfigure*)Qtoken.pData)->patientProfile) seems to be wrong.

Remember: I got pData, which is a void pointer. This needs to be casted to a tdWAKDAllStateConfigure pointer so i can get a pointer to the member patientProfile(which is    a  tdPatientProfile) of it. Where is my fault?

Comment: By "char pointer `name[50]`", do you mean `char *name[50]`?

Comment: It's really hard to say without some more code. You only show two code fragments, and the relation between them isn't clear.

Comment: No, it's char name[50]; inside patientProfile. Thanks for mentioning

Comment: What's the definition of these structs?

Answer (score 0):

This is nothing but a wild-ass guess, but whenever I see strncpy( ) I get nervous. I'm sure that you know that strncpy( ) is evil in that it does not always properly terminate the destination string. Could that be your problem?

You also might want to consider making arg3 of strncpy be sizeof(name)-1, or anyway something safer than passedChars.

I'm willing to bet that the problem has nothing to do with casting a void*: that's what void* is *for*, after all -- to hold a pointer to any type. If compare the void* and the char* after the cast, I think you'll see that they are identical bit-for-bit.

Comment: passedChars is 16 in my test cases so this shouldn't be the problem. i null-terminate it after the strncpy call: destination[passedChars] = '\0'; // null-terminate
 (*ptr) += passedChars + 1; - the code crashes before this statement.

Comment: @Jevermeister -- But the crash happens after the strncpy(), right? Or no? If yes, then check how name is terminated. Sometimes (if I recall correctly) strncpy() puts the NUL ***after*** the last char of the destination string, i.e., at name[passedChars + 1]. In any case, strncpy() is definitely an unsafe way to copy strings. I never use it any more, myself. (For counted strings, I use memmove( ) always, which is dependable.) (Count on me for the unsolicited advice :-)

Comment: Got it. Thanks for your replies. The correct answer is &(((tdWAKDAllStateConfigure *)(Qtoken.pData))->patientProfile) , the ( in front of Qtoken.pData was missing...

Comment: Excellent! Congrats on finding that invisible typo.